# How is this type of piecewise function represented and calculated?

Tags: functions, recursion, piecewise

How is this type of piecewise function as follows in the picture represented and calculated?

[image]

Use:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Cos[(\[Pi] x)/2], x <= 0}, {f[x - 1] + 1, x > 0}}]
```

This prompt appears：

[image]

The process of calculating the corresponding function value is as follows: such as `f[2]`

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to use SetDelayed.

Comment: In[5]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Cos[(\[Pi] x)/2], x <= 0}, {f[x - 1] + 1, x > 0}}]

In[7]:= f[2]

Out[7]= 3

Comment: As a general rule, I tend to write any function definition using `SetDelayed` as a matter of course, unless I have a special reason not to do so (and add a `ClearAll[functionName]` before the definition as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_?NumericQ] :=
 Piecewise[{{Cos[(π x)/2], x <= 0}, {f[x - 1] + 1, x > 0}}]

Plot[f[x], {x, -6, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of ```x_?NumericQ```?

Comment: It keeps the function from evaluating unless the argument is numeric. See the documentation for [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)

Comment: @csn899 See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037